# Big red X on image and I cannot detect error

Tags: c#, uwp, aforge

To be brief, I'm trying to implement some motion detection algorithm and in my case I'm working on UWP using portable version of AForge library to processing image. Avoiding this issue, I have problem with conversion SoftwareBitmap object (that I get from MediaFrameReader) to Bitmap object (and vice versa) that I use in my code associated with motion detection. In consequence of this conversion, I get proper image with big red X in the foreground. Code below:

```
private async void FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
    {
        var frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();
        if (frame != null && !_detectingMotion)
        {
            SoftwareBitmap aForgeInputBitmap = null;
            var inputBitmap = frame.VideoMediaFrame?.SoftwareBitmap;
            if (inputBitmap != null)
            {
                _detectingMotion = true;
                //The XAML Image control can only display images in BRGA8 format with premultiplied or no alpha
                if (inputBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat == BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8
                    && inputBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode == BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied)
                {
                    aForgeInputBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Copy(inputBitmap);
                }
                else
                {
                    aForgeInputBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(inputBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore);
                }
                await _aForgeHelper.MoveBackgrounds(aForgeInputBitmap);
                SoftwareBitmap aForgeOutputBitmap = await _aForgeHelper.DetectMotion();
                _frameRenderer.PresentSoftwareBitmap(aForgeOutputBitmap);
                _detectingMotion = false;
            }
        }
    }

class AForgeHelper
{
    private Bitmap _background;
    private Bitmap _currentFrameBitmap;

    public async Task MoveBackgrounds(SoftwareBitmap currentFrame)
    {
        if (_background == null)
        {
            _background = TransformToGrayscale(await ConvertSoftwareBitmapToBitmap(currentFrame));
        }
        else
        {
            // modifying _background in compliance with algorithm - in this case irrelevant
        }
    }

    public async Task<SoftwareBitmap> DetectMotion()
    {
        // to check only this conversion
        return await ConvertBitmapToSoftwareBitmap(_background);
    }

    private static async Task<Bitmap> ConvertSoftwareBitmapToBitmap(SoftwareBitmap input)
    {
        Bitmap output = null;
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            WriteableBitmap tmpBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(input.PixelWidth, input.PixelHeight);
            input.CopyToBuffer(tmpBitmap.PixelBuffer);
            output = (Bitmap)tmpBitmap;
        });
        return output;
    }

    private static async Task<SoftwareBitmap> ConvertBitmapToSoftwareBitmap(Bitmap input)
    {
        SoftwareBitmap output = null;
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            WriteableBitmap tmpBitmap = (WriteableBitmap)input;
            output = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, tmpBitmap.PixelWidth, tmpBitmap.PixelHeight,
                                        BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
            output.CopyFromBuffer(tmpBitmap.PixelBuffer);
        });
        return output;
    }

    private static Bitmap TransformToGrayscale(Bitmap input)
    {
        Grayscale grayscaleFilter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
        Bitmap output = grayscaleFilter.Apply(input);
        return output;
    }
```

Certainly, I've tried to detect some errors using try-catch clauses. I've found nothing. Thanks in advance.

EDIT (29/03/2018):

Generally, my app targets at providing some features associated with Kinect Sensor. App user has possibility to choose some feature from features list. First of all, this app have to be available on Xbox One, therefore I've chosen UWP. Due to 'scientific' issues, I've implemented MVVM pattern, using MVVM Light framework. As for *PresentSoftwareBitmap()* method, it comes from Windows-universal-samples repo and I paste FrameRenderer helper class below:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("5B0D3235-4DBA-4D44-865E-8F1D0E4FD04D")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
unsafe interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess
{
    void GetBuffer(out byte* buffer, out uint capacity);
}

class FrameRenderer
{
    private Image _imageElement;
    private SoftwareBitmap _backBuffer;
    private bool _taskRunning = false;

    public FrameRenderer(Image imageElement)
    {
        _imageElement = imageElement;
        _imageElement.Source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
    }

    // Processes a MediaFrameReference and displays it in a XAML image control
    public void ProcessFrame(MediaFrameReference frame)
    {
        var softwareBitmap = FrameRenderer.ConvertToDisplayableImage(frame?.VideoMediaFrame);
        if (softwareBitmap != null)
        {
            // Swap the processed frame to _backBuffer and trigger UI thread to render it
            softwareBitmap = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _backBuffer, softwareBitmap);

            // UI thread always reset _backBuffer before using it.  Unused bitmap should be disposed.
            softwareBitmap?.Dispose();

            // Changes to xaml ImageElement must happen in UI thread through Dispatcher
            var task = _imageElement.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                async () =>
                {
                    // Don't let two copies of this task run at the same time.
                    if (_taskRunning)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    _taskRunning = true;

                    // Keep draining frames from the backbuffer until the backbuffer is empty.
                    SoftwareBitmap latestBitmap;
                    while ((latestBitmap = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _backBuffer, null)) != null)
                    {
                        var imageSource = (SoftwareBitmapSource)_imageElement.Source;
                        await imageSource.SetBitmapAsync(latestBitmap);
                        latestBitmap.Dispose();
                    }

                    _taskRunning = false;
                });
        }
    }



    // Function delegate that transforms a scanline from an input image to an output image.
    private unsafe delegate void TransformScanline(int pixelWidth, byte* inputRowBytes, byte* outputRowBytes);
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines the subtype to request from the MediaFrameReader that will result in
    /// a frame that can be rendered by ConvertToDisplayableImage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Subtype string to request, or null if subtype is not renderable.</returns>

    public static string GetSubtypeForFrameReader(MediaFrameSourceKind kind, MediaFrameFormat format)
    {
        // Note that media encoding subtypes may differ in case.
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingSubtypes

        string subtype = format.Subtype;
        switch (kind)
        {
            // For color sources, we accept anything and request that it be converted to Bgra8.
            case MediaFrameSourceKind.Color:
                return Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingSubtypes.Bgra8;

            // The only depth format we can render is D16.
            case MediaFrameSourceKind.Depth:
                return String.Equals(subtype, Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingSubtypes.D16, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? subtype : null;

            // The only infrared formats we can render are L8 and L16.
            case MediaFrameSourceKind.Infrared:
                return (String.Equals(subtype, Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingSubtypes.L8, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    String.Equals(subtype, Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingSubtypes.L16, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ? subtype : null;

            // No other source kinds are supported by this class.
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a frame to a SoftwareBitmap of a valid format to display in an Image control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputFrame">Frame to convert.</param>

    public static unsafe SoftwareBitmap ConvertToDisplayableImage(VideoMediaFrame inputFrame)
    {
        SoftwareBitmap result = null;
        using (var inputBitmap = inputFrame?.SoftwareBitmap)
        {
            if (inputBitmap != null)
            {
                switch (inputFrame.FrameReference.SourceKind)
                {
                    case MediaFrameSourceKind.Color:
                        // XAML requires Bgra8 with premultiplied alpha.
                        // We requested Bgra8 from the MediaFrameReader, so all that's
                        // left is fixing the alpha channel if necessary.
                        if (inputBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Color frame in unexpected format.");
                        }
                        else if (inputBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode == BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied)
                        {
                            // Already in the correct format.
                            result = SoftwareBitmap.Copy(inputBitmap);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Convert to premultiplied alpha.
                            result = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(inputBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MediaFrameSourceKind.Depth:
                        // We requested D16 from the MediaFrameReader, so the frame should
                        // be in Gray16 format.
                        if (inputBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat == BitmapPixelFormat.Gray16)
                        {
                            // Use a special pseudo color to render 16 bits depth frame.
                            var depthScale = (float)inputFrame.DepthMediaFrame.DepthFormat.DepthScaleInMeters;
                            var minReliableDepth = inputFrame.DepthMediaFrame.MinReliableDepth;
                            var maxReliableDepth = inputFrame.DepthMediaFrame.MaxReliableDepth;
                            result = TransformBitmap(inputBitmap, (w, i, o) => PseudoColorHelper.PseudoColorForDepth(w, i, o, depthScale, minReliableDepth, maxReliableDepth));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Depth frame in unexpected format.");
                        }
                        break;

                    case MediaFrameSourceKind.Infrared:
                        // We requested L8 or L16 from the MediaFrameReader, so the frame should
                        // be in Gray8 or Gray16 format. 
                        switch (inputBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat)
                        {
                            case BitmapPixelFormat.Gray16:
                                // Use pseudo color to render 16 bits frames.
                                result = TransformBitmap(inputBitmap, PseudoColorHelper.PseudoColorFor16BitInfrared);
                                break;

                            case BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8:
                                // Use pseudo color to render 8 bits frames.
                                result = TransformBitmap(inputBitmap, PseudoColorHelper.PseudoColorFor8BitInfrared);
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Infrared frame in unexpected format.");
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Transform image into Bgra8 image using given transform method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="softwareBitmap">Input image to transform.</param>
    /// <param name="transformScanline">Method to map pixels in a scanline.</param>

    private static unsafe SoftwareBitmap TransformBitmap(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap, TransformScanline transformScanline)
    {
        // XAML Image control only supports premultiplied Bgra8 format.
        var outputBitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, softwareBitmap.PixelHeight, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

        using (var input = softwareBitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.Read))
        using (var output = outputBitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.Write))
        {
            // Get stride values to calculate buffer position for a given pixel x and y position.
            int inputStride = input.GetPlaneDescription(0).Stride;
            int outputStride = output.GetPlaneDescription(0).Stride;
            int pixelWidth = softwareBitmap.PixelWidth;
            int pixelHeight = softwareBitmap.PixelHeight;

            using (var outputReference = output.CreateReference())
            using (var inputReference = input.CreateReference())
            {
                // Get input and output byte access buffers.
                byte* inputBytes;
                uint inputCapacity;
                ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)inputReference).GetBuffer(out inputBytes, out inputCapacity);
                byte* outputBytes;
                uint outputCapacity;
                ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)outputReference).GetBuffer(out outputBytes, out outputCapacity);

                // Iterate over all pixels and store converted value.
                for (int y = 0; y < pixelHeight; y++)
                {
                    byte* inputRowBytes = inputBytes + y * inputStride;
                    byte* outputRowBytes = outputBytes + y * outputStride;

                    transformScanline(pixelWidth, inputRowBytes, outputRowBytes);
                }
            }
        }

        return outputBitmap;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// A helper class to manage look-up-table for pseudo-colors.
    /// </summary>

    private static class PseudoColorHelper
    {
        #region Constructor, private members and methods

        private const int TableSize = 1024;   // Look up table size
        private static readonly uint[] PseudoColorTable;
        private static readonly uint[] InfraredRampTable;

        // Color palette mapping value from 0 to 1 to blue to red colors.
        private static readonly Color[] ColorRamp =
        {
            Color.FromArgb(a:0xFF, r:0x7F, g:0x00, b:0x00),
            Color.FromArgb(a:0xFF, r:0xFF, g:0x00, b:0x00),
            Color.FromArgb(a:0xFF, r:0xFF, g:0x7F, b:0x00),
            Color.FromArgb(a:0xFF, r:0xFF, g:0xFF, b:0x00),
            Color.FromArgb(a:0xFF, r:0x7F, g:0xFF, b:0x7F),
            Color.FromArgb(a:0xFF, r:0x00, g:0xFF, b:0xFF),
            Color.FromArgb(a:0xFF, r:0x00, g:0x7F, b:0xFF),
            Color.FromArgb(a:0xFF, r:0x00, g:0x00, b:0xFF),
            Color.FromArgb(a:0xFF, r:0x00, g:0x00, b:0x7F),
        };

        static PseudoColorHelper()
        {
            PseudoColorTable = InitializePseudoColorLut();
            InfraredRampTable = InitializeInfraredRampLut();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Maps an input infrared value between [0, 1] to corrected value between [0, 1].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Input value between [0, 1].</param>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]  // Tell the compiler to inline this method to improve performance

        private static uint InfraredColor(float value)
        {
            int index = (int)(value * TableSize);
            index = index < 0 ? 0 : index > TableSize - 1 ? TableSize - 1 : index;
            return InfraredRampTable[index];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the pseudo-color look up table for infrared pixels
        /// </summary>

        private static uint[] InitializeInfraredRampLut()
        {
            uint[] lut = new uint[TableSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < TableSize; i++)
            {
                var value = (float)i / TableSize;
                // Adjust to increase color change between lower values in infrared images

                var alpha = (float)Math.Pow(1 - value, 12);
                lut[i] = ColorRampInterpolation(alpha);
            }

            return lut;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes pseudo-color look up table for depth pixels
        /// </summary>
        private static uint[] InitializePseudoColorLut()
        {
            uint[] lut = new uint[TableSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < TableSize; i++)
            {
                lut[i] = ColorRampInterpolation((float)i / TableSize);
            }

            return lut;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Maps a float value to a pseudo-color pixel
        /// </summary>
        private static uint ColorRampInterpolation(float value)
        {
            // Map value to surrounding indexes on the color ramp
            int rampSteps = ColorRamp.Length - 1;
            float scaled = value * rampSteps;
            int integer = (int)scaled;
            int index =
                integer < 0 ? 0 :
                integer >= rampSteps - 1 ? rampSteps - 1 :
                integer;

            Color prev = ColorRamp[index];
            Color next = ColorRamp[index + 1];

            // Set color based on ratio of closeness between the surrounding colors
            uint alpha = (uint)((scaled - integer) * 255);
            uint beta = 255 - alpha;
            return
                ((prev.A * beta + next.A * alpha) / 255) << 24 | // Alpha
                ((prev.R * beta + next.R * alpha) / 255) << 16 | // Red
                ((prev.G * beta + next.G * alpha) / 255) << 8 |  // Green
                ((prev.B * beta + next.B * alpha) / 255);        // Blue
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Maps a value in [0, 1] to a pseudo RGBA color.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Input value between [0, 1].</param>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]

        private static uint PseudoColor(float value)
        {
            int index = (int)(value * TableSize);
            index = index < 0 ? 0 : index > TableSize - 1 ? TableSize - 1 : index;
            return PseudoColorTable[index];
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Maps each pixel in a scanline from a 16 bit depth value to a pseudo-color pixel.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pixelWidth">Width of the input scanline, in pixels.</param>
        /// <param name="inputRowBytes">Pointer to the start of the input scanline.</param>
        /// <param name="outputRowBytes">Pointer to the start of the output scanline.</param>
        /// <param name="depthScale">Physical distance that corresponds to one unit in the input scanline.</param>
        /// <param name="minReliableDepth">Shortest distance at which the sensor can provide reliable measurements.</param>
        /// <param name="maxReliableDepth">Furthest distance at which the sensor can provide reliable measurements.</param>

        public static unsafe void PseudoColorForDepth(int pixelWidth, byte* inputRowBytes, byte* outputRowBytes, float depthScale, float minReliableDepth, float maxReliableDepth)
        {
            // Visualize space in front of your desktop.
            float minInMeters = minReliableDepth * depthScale;
            float maxInMeters = maxReliableDepth * depthScale;
            float one_min = 1.0f / minInMeters;
            float range = 1.0f / maxInMeters - one_min;

            ushort* inputRow = (ushort*)inputRowBytes;
            uint* outputRow = (uint*)outputRowBytes;

            for (int x = 0; x < pixelWidth; x++)
            {
                var depth = inputRow[x] * depthScale;

                if (depth == 0)
                {
                    // Map invalid depth values to transparent pixels.
                    // This happens when depth information cannot be calculated, e.g. when objects are too close.
                    outputRow[x] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    var alpha = (1.0f / depth - one_min) / range;
                    outputRow[x] = PseudoColor(alpha * alpha);
                }
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Maps each pixel in a scanline from a 8 bit infrared value to a pseudo-color pixel.
        /// </summary>
        /// /// <param name="pixelWidth">Width of the input scanline, in pixels.</param>
        /// <param name="inputRowBytes">Pointer to the start of the input scanline.</param>
        /// <param name="outputRowBytes">Pointer to the start of the output scanline.</param>

        public static unsafe void PseudoColorFor8BitInfrared(
            int pixelWidth, byte* inputRowBytes, byte* outputRowBytes)
        {
            byte* inputRow = inputRowBytes;
            uint* outputRow = (uint*)outputRowBytes;

            for (int x = 0; x < pixelWidth; x++)
            {
                outputRow[x] = InfraredColor(inputRow[x] / (float)Byte.MaxValue);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Maps each pixel in a scanline from a 16 bit infrared value to a pseudo-color pixel.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pixelWidth">Width of the input scanline.</param>
        /// <param name="inputRowBytes">Pointer to the start of the input scanline.</param>
        /// <param name="outputRowBytes">Pointer to the start of the output scanline.</param>

        public static unsafe void PseudoColorFor16BitInfrared(int pixelWidth, byte* inputRowBytes, byte* outputRowBytes)
        {
            ushort* inputRow = (ushort*)inputRowBytes;
            uint* outputRow = (uint*)outputRowBytes;

            for (int x = 0; x < pixelWidth; x++)
            {
                outputRow[x] = InfraredColor(inputRow[x] / (float)UInt16.MaxValue);
            }
        }
    }


    // Displays the provided softwareBitmap in a XAML image control.
    public void PresentSoftwareBitmap(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap)
    {
        if (softwareBitmap != null)
        {
            // Swap the processed frame to _backBuffer and trigger UI thread to render it
            softwareBitmap = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _backBuffer, softwareBitmap);

            // UI thread always reset _backBuffer before using it.  Unused bitmap should be disposed.
            softwareBitmap?.Dispose();

            // Changes to xaml ImageElement must happen in UI thread through Dispatcher
            var task = _imageElement.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                async () =>
                {
                    // Don't let two copies of this task run at the same time.
                    if (_taskRunning)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    _taskRunning = true;

                    // Keep draining frames from the backbuffer until the backbuffer is empty.
                    SoftwareBitmap latestBitmap;
                    while ((latestBitmap = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _backBuffer, null)) != null)
                    {
                        var imageSource = (SoftwareBitmapSource)_imageElement.Source;
                        await imageSource.SetBitmapAsync(latestBitmap);
                        latestBitmap.Dispose();
                    }

                    _taskRunning = false;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

This is output image, that I've got after conversion issues and grayscale process:
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TccsJ.png)

As for VS version - Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, Version 15.6.1 (to be precise). Once more, thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in the debugger output? The Big Red X is normally an indication for an exception drawing the control, such as the file not being there or missing memory.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't got any messages about exceptions in the debugger output. Therefore, I decided to ask this question.

Comment: After another tests, I'm sure that problem is strictly associated with casting WriteableBitmap to Bitmap (or vice versa) using defined operator but I don't know how it should be solved.

Comment: What is your foreground code? Did  you mean the image control show a red X? How you defined the `PresentSoftwareBitmap` method? Your code snippet are not enough to reproduce your issue. What's your VS version?

Comment: I've added information that you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe stupid assumption, but this red x (cross) is simply watermark that  is applied during cast procedure?